# Cannot get "Constrain to margins" to work on in Interface Builder in Xcode

Tags: ios, constraints

> Cannot get "Constrain to margins" to work on in Interface Builder in Xcode.

I'm learning iOS development through Apple's official Swift tutorial: [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH5-SW1)

My problem is that I cannot position my StackView properly using "Constrain to margins" with Auto Layout - there is no margin to its superview.

"Constrain to margins" is still gray after being clicked (see below). After adding constraints (left: 0, right: 0), the StackView is positioned with no margin to its superview, while margin is present to both sides in the tutorial.

How can I fix this?

"Constrain to margins" is gray:
[image]

No margin to either side of StackView:
[image]

The added constraints:
[image]

Comment: Select the leading or trailing constraint you just created and look at it in the attributes inspector. There is a pop-down menu showing what is constrained to what. Check Relative To Margin if it is not already checked.

Comment: @matt - Thanks, but checking that and setting "Constant" to 0 still position to StackView at the edge of the screen.

Comment: @Shuzheng - show another picture, after you've added the top, leading and trailing constraints, but with the `>Constraints` expanded (in the Document Outline pane) so we can see how the constraints are listed.

Comment: @DonMag - I've added the screenshot per your request. Can the reason that I cannot "Constraint to margins" be the so-called "Safe Area"?

Answer (score 2):

Select the first constraint (trailing to trailing) and look at the Size inspector. Pop up the first popup menu.

[image]

Change from Safe Area to Superview. Check Relative to Margin.

[image]

Change the constant to 0, and now the trailing edge of the stack view is at the margin.

[image]

---

(But I can't explain your original quandary. I've never seen the margins checkbox grayed out like that. Mine isn't.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @matt - it works. I just started a new iOS Xcode project, like the tutorial says. Does your "Constrain to margins" work, so that you don't have to go through the steps you outlined above?

Comment: It is not grayed out, but the resulting constraints are still to the safe area and have to be retargeted by editing as my answer indicates.

Comment: You call this the "official tutorial" but do note that it's in the _documentation archive_, meaning that it is not supported any longer. As you suggest, the instructions in it may predate the existence of the safe area. So this might not be a good way for you to get started. Who knows what other issues you may encounter?

Comment: thanks. Do you have some other suggestion for getting started?

Answer (score 0):

*"Constrain to margins" is still gray after being clicked...*

If you can click and toggle the checkmark on and off, my guess is it just *looks* like it is grayed out.

As to the actual constraints, I think this is just a misunderstanding of how the `safe area` works.

When designing with `View as: iPhone 8` you won't see any effect from the safe area.

This is iPhone 8, with the stack view constrained Top / Leading / Trailing all at 0 (zero):

[image]

If we switch to landscape orientation, this is what we see:

[image]

Both of which are correct.

If we don't make any changes, but switch to `View as: iPhone 11 Pro`, this is what we see:

[image]

[image]

Notice that the frame of the stack view moves to allow room for the Notch at one end and the soft-home-button at the other... in other words, it is respecting the Safe-Area.